# woocommerce api ovveride function

Tags: api, woocommerce, categories

I have a problem with woocommerce api, I need to get categories with a request like this:

wc-api/v3/products/categories?consumer_key=key&consumer_secret=key1

the key are correct but the problem is that only user with "manage_product_terms" capatibilies can use this api, while I need to display the categories for all the user...there is a way for override this function "get_product_categories"?
or there is a way for show the cateogries without "manage_product_terms" capatibilies?

Answer (score 0):

1. Hook to products api `add_action('woocommerce_api_products'`
2. Add `user_has_cap` filter `add_filter(`
3. Filter injects a capabilities array `function($caps){`
4. Modify array index of `manage_product_terms` to true `$caps[index]=true`
5. return the filtered capabilities array `return $caps`